# Python Discord.py tasks TypeError 'method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, methods, discord, discord.py, typeerror

i'm a French Discord bot Developer bot I have an error on my background tasks:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("prêt")


async def ch_pr():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()

    statuses = [
        "0help ou 0?", f"Sur {len(bot.guilds)} serveurs !",
        "Fait en discord.py !", 
        str(len(set(bot.get_all_members))) + "utilisateurs du bot!"
    ]

    while not bot.is_closed():

        status = random.choice(statuses)

        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=status))

        await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

My error is:

```
File main.py,line 38 in ch_pr:
str(len(set(bot.get_all_members))) + "utilisateurs du bot!"
TypeError: Name 'method' object is not iterable.
```

Thanks for help. I'm coding with repl.it

Comment: Hey, your question is quite specific. Stackoverflow thrives on questions that can solve problems that affect many people. A good first step could be to change your posts title to be more generic and inclusive (it makes your question easier to answer and easier to be found. SO is not a debugging platform but an encyclopedia based around  user feedback. Please consider looking at the following link for a better feel as to how to write a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

It's a *method*, not an *attribute*. You need to actually *call* the method as well.

```py
bot.get_all_members()
```

Mind the brackets `()`.

Also, don't spam-change your status, Discord won't appreciate that & you'll get rate-limited. Try doing it once every minute or so.

Comment: If it worked you should mark my answer as correct